# How do I create one button, but make it have two functions?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I created two separate buttons, start and stop, for a stopwatch. How do I combine that into one button. Click start, the timer starts, then the function should change so when clicked it would stop, then when clicked again, it would reset.

```
    @IBAction func start(sender: AnyObject) {
     if !timer.valid{
    let aSelector : Selector = "updateTime"
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: aSelector, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()


    }
}

@IBAction func stop(sender: AnyObject) {
    timer.invalidate()
}
```

Comment: Take a bool variable to start and stop .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as follows.

```
@IBAction func startstop(sender: AnyObject) {
    if !timer.valid{
        let aSelector : Selector = "updateTime"
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: aSelector, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
    }
    else{
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Else you can take one flag as `boolean`.

You can check by true or false as by conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Use button selected and unselected state 
as you can assign different images to the button  for different states

```
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"touch_selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"touch_selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

after that use

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
     // use you if statement to select the condition for start and stop 
     if ([_button isSelected]){
         // start function
     } else {
         //stop function 
     }
}
```

sorry for that the code is the mixture of Obj c and swift